# Laravel event with socket-io [receive notifications]

Tags: php, laravel, socket.io

For the first time attempt with `laravel` and `socket-io` I am trying to send very simple notification to admins. **So far my event is firing but I need help with receiving event notifications**.

## Logic

*It's very basic because I want to understand the process.*

1. User opens page `Add Product`
2. Admin gets notification that `user X` is in `App Product` page.

**So far**

So far I can fire event and get user data (user that is in `Add Product` page)

**Need help for**

I need help to understand the way that admin receives notifications.

## Code

Component script

```
created() {
  let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))
  this.listenForBroadcast(user);
},
methods: {
  listenForBroadcast(user) {
    Echo.join('userInAddProduct')
    .here((Loggeduser) => {
      console.log('My user data', Loggeduser);
    });
  }
}
```

**Result of code above**

```
My user data [{…}]
  0:
    id: 1
    name: "Test User"
    photo: "User-1588137335.png"
    __ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
    get id: ƒ reactiveGetter()
    set id: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
    get name: ƒ reactiveGetter()
    set name: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
    get photo: ƒ reactiveGetter()
    set photo: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

Channels route

```
Broadcast::channel('userInAddProduct', function ($user) {
    return [
        'id' => $user->id,
        'photo' => $user->photo,
        'name' => $user->name
    ];
});
```

MessagePushed (event file)

```
class MessagePushed implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('userInAddProduct');
    }
}
```

**Question**

How can I receive notification about this event fire? I want to notify my admin users that `user x` is in page `Add Product`?

## Update

Since I published this question I've made some changes and here is my latest code + questions.

`bootstrap.js`

```
window.io = require('socket.io-client');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
    auth: { // added authentication token (because all my events are private)
        headers: {
            Authorization: localStorage.getItem('access_token'),
        },
    },
});
```

`Add.vue (add product component where event has to be fired)`

```
listenForBroadcast(user) {
    let ui = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))
    Echo.join('userInAddProduct')
    .here((users) => {
        console.log('My user data', users)
    })
    .joining((user) => {
        this.$notify({
            title: '',
            message: user + 'joining',
            offset: 100,
            type: 'success'
        });
    })
    .leaving((user) => {
        this.$notify({
            title: '',
            message: user + 'is leaving new product',
            offset: 100,
            type: 'warning'
        });
    })
    .whisper('typing', (e) => {
        this.$notify({
            title: '',
            message: ui.username + 'is adding new product',
            offset: 100,
            type: 'success'
        })
    })
    .listenForWhisper('typing', (e) => {
        console.log(e)
        this.$notify({
            title: '',
            message: ui.username + 'is entered add new product page.',
            offset: 100,
            type: 'success'
        });
    })
    .notification((notification) => {
        console.log('noitication listener: ', notification.type);
    });
},
```

Then I've made 4 files to handle events:

- Event (`passing data`)
- Event Listener (`process the database storage` and `showing notifications` to online admins)
- Observer (firing event)
- Notification (`store data to database` for admins in case when event fire they're not online so they can see notifications later on)

`Event file`

```
class MessagePushed extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    public $product;

    public function __construct(User $user, Product $product)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('userInAddProduct');
    }
}
```

`Listener file`

```
class ThingToDoAfterEventWasFired implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function handle(MessagePushed $event)
    {
        //Log testing purpose only
        $user = $event->user->username;
        $product = $event->product->name;

        // Real data that should be broadcasts
        $user2 = $event->user;
        $product2 = $event->product;

        // inform all admins and authorized staffs about new product
        $admins = User::role(['admin', 'staff'])->get();
        foreach($admins as $admin) {
            $admin->notify(new UserAddProduct($user2, $product2));
        }

        Log::info("Product $product was Created, by worker: $user");
    }
}
```

`Notification`

```
class UserAddProduct extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $product;
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(User $user, Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database', 'broadcast'];
    }

    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => $this->user->id,
            'user_username' => $this->user->username,
            'product_id' => $this->product->id,
            'product_name' => $this->product->name,
        ];
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'read_at' => null,
            'data' => [
                'user_id' => $this->user->id,
                'user_username' => $this->user->username,
                'product_id' => $this->product->id,
                'product_name' => $this->product->name,
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

`Observer`

```
public function created(Product $product)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    event(new MessagePushed($user, $product));
}
```

#### Questions

1. How can I return live notifications as soon as event is fired **in whole app**? currently as my code is placed in `add.vue component admins get notify IF they are in same page only :/`
2. How do I get notifications of multiple event? let say I have another `event, listener, observer` for other page actions I want admin be notified of both `product event` and `other event` in whole app.

thanks

Comment: Are u using socket.io : https://socket.io/docs/ in your client-side ? if it was you can simply implement with socket.on('event_fire_name', function(){ /* */ }); to receive the notification in the Admin panel

Comment: @AhmedRebai yes i am using socket in client side, do you have any sample code that you might share as answer?

Comment: @maforis Just check official docs https://socket.io/docs/client-api/, it will guide you

Comment: ....No one?! :/

Comment: As Websocket server, do you use Laravel Echo Server? Is your frontend a SPA? Optionally use Docker? If I understood well, you wish monitoring in real-time people who enter/leave some page? Depending on your answers(especially about Laravel Echo Server), I could help you

Comment: @Shizzen83 `1` yes, i am using laravel `echo, redis and socket` in my laravel vue app. `2` No. I'm not using docker. `3` yes for learning purpose i am trying to monitor enter/leave people in specific page (but show notification of it in all pages).

Comment: Ok, you didn't answer about SPA, but as you said "in all pages", I guess your frontend use many HTML pages instead of a single one.

Comment: @Shizzen83 I said `in my laravel vue app` the answer is yes i am using SPA. my front-end runs on vuejs components and not blades.

Comment: Oh my bad then, perfect, it will be much easier within a SPA. I'm working right now, I will answer a very long tutorial when I can, probably tonight. Waiting for it, already some tips, you will need this https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server#presence-channels to notify your Redis which already acts as a gateway Laravel => Echo Server, but this time, it will do Echo Server => Laravel, and you will need https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redis#pubsub to listen to Redis. See you tonight.

Comment: @Shizzen83 thank you so much, can't wait to see it :)

Comment: @Shizzen83 there still night not coming? :)

Comment: @mafortis I already did it for myself in a project, but as someone else needs it, I'm transforming it into a Composer package, it asks a lot of time, I will try to post it today

Comment: @mafortis Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214180/discussion-between-shizzen83-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved

Here is how I done it based on my need and my question (it might be somehow different if your case is different than mine)

In component that activity happens (in my case `Add.vue`)

```
Echo.join('userInAddProduct')
.here((users) => {
    console.log('here: ', users);
})
.joining((user) => {
    console.log('joining: ', user);
})
.leaving((user) => {
    console.log('leaving: ', user);
})
.whisper('typing', {data: notf}) // this part sends my data
.notification((notification) => {
    console.log('noitication listener1: ', notification.type);
});
```

As I needed my notification be visible in all pages to admins I've added my socket emit (i.e. `Echo.listenForWhisper`) into my navbar component.

```
mounted() {
  this.notifs();
    window.Echo.join('userInAddProduct')
       // listen to broadcast from Add.vue
      .listenForWhisper('typing', (product) => {
        // add it into my navbar notifications list
        this.notifications.unshift(product);
      });
}
```

Now each time user adds new product to server admin gets notified.

**note** To see my other settings for this function to happen please scroll back to my update part and see `Event, Listener & Observe` files code. (you make those files and all this codes above to your preferred components then you'll have real time notifications).

Answer (score 1):

We differentiate channel types like **public and private**.

**Public**: Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel. It works without any authentication, so anonymus users can listen to this broadcast. Like football match scores available for everyone.

**Private**: Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel. It works with an authentication, so only authenticated users can listen to this broadcast. Like admins watching what specific users do or user watching their orders status.

On the otherhand there is **another private** channel which is Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel. Also require authentication. In example would be much like an any chat room. Ex.: only authenticated users can communicate with each other.

So these types will define your method. And you have to follow different paths. I am very suggesting to read the *Laravel documentation* (https://laravel.com/docs/broadcasting), it will guide you very carefully.

In the **routes/channels.php** you have to decide or verify if the authenticated user can listen on this particular channel. So you have to return boolean value (true or false). So here, you are not returning any value to the client side.

**Every public property** in your MessagePushed broadcast event will be **serialized** and **sent** to the **client side**. You have to give every informational data to the MessagePushed constructor and set to property/properties. Now you can handle the received data by like that, ex:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
    auth: {
      headers: {
        'X-Auth-Token': "<token>"
      }
    }
});

window.Echo.private('userInAddProduct')
   .listen('MessagePushed ', (e) => {
       console.log(e.auction);
    });
```

I recommend to create custom authentication with token usage. Above I sent token to the server to authenticate user. https://laravel.com/docs/authentication#adding-custom-guards

In your situation I would separate these two mechanism.

1. check the user for going to the App Product page
2. notify the admin

For the 2. point would be enough to use the Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel. So there is need for websocket on the admin page.
The 1. point could be tricky, because it's depends on your requirments. It is enough to notify the admin about user goes to exact App Product page?

- If yes, then you will trigger this broadcast event in your controller when user goes to that page.
- If not enough, then you need another websocket on the user page to "poll" your server and send tick broadcast to the admin in every X seconds.

Trigger broadcast event:

```
broadcast(new App\Events\MessagePushed($user));
```

---

My taste of usage is:

- client side: [socket.io-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client)
- sever side: [laravel-echo-server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server)
- redis broadcaster
- custom authentication mechanism

Hope, I could help!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, would you mind check my update? I think that might help you to understand my issue therefore helping me better :) appreciate it.

Comment: I think you are on wrong path to achieve your goal. How I said the PresenceChannel is like chatroom, not exactly the best option for monitoring users. Which way do you want to notify admin users, only with websocket?

Comment: honestly I'm a bit confused with this, my general plan is this: if admin is online (in any page) get live notification. if he's offline notification stores in database and he see it as soon as he becomes online.

Comment: what do you suggest?

Comment: In this situation I would create script for admin users, which will load on every page, this script contains the socket.io connection. (window.Echo = new Echo...). You can include this script when the user is admin. These specific controllers would call some CustomHandlerClass to store the viewing action into the database. So maybe you can create a Monitoring model to store and get user views. Also you can trigger broadcast in this CustomHandlerClass "broadcast(new App\Events\MessagePushed($user));". So you will store everytime into the database, but you send broadcast too.

Comment: If the admin is online, then it will receive the the broadcast "notification". Therefor the MessagePushed class **does not** have to extends the Event class. This broadcast would be PrivateChannel. I am prefer the broadcast() method instead of event() call, when it's actually a broadcast. You can create page or something to display every Monitoring object. (which user, which page viewed and when). Ps.: You can extend the monitoring option with route names. You can get the actual route name from the request object to store it into the Monitoring model/object.

Comment: hmm, the logic in words got a bit complex :). anyhow regarding to your script suggestion, the `window.Echo = new Echo({` is available in all views as my main js file. so would that be useful somehow?

Comment: I would restrict this section of the code into separated script. Because you want to give this option/feature to admin users only. Plus better to make it (more) secure.

Comment: it's laravel default afraid if move it out broke the app.

Comment: **Simple and short version:** Include the broadcast listening script on every page, but only for admin users. Store the view action into the database everytime on the specific pages/routes. (You can handle this from controller maybe.) Also broadcast a PrivateChannel to notify the admins. You can simple create one page for admins where they can see all the user views, because they *(the admins)* were offline.

Comment: Not exactly understand why would broke your app?! You should check out the webpack asset handling.

Comment: anything helped?

Answer (score -1):

I recently wrote an article [How to use Laravel WebSockets for NuxtJs notifications](https://andreyblog.com/how-to-use-laravel-websockets-for-nuxtjs-notifications/) where I described in sufficient detail including the event setting for Laravel WebSockets. I hope you find it useful.

Comment: thank you i will read it and come back to you if didn't work or have any problem

Comment: Ok you lost me on nuxt config file, I do not use nuxt (not even installed in my app) but the config you placed there is already exist in my `bootstrap.js` file (you can see it in update part) whats your suggestion?